# Where does middleware save token?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, owin, openid-connect

I have a startup middleware written in vb.net. It successfully logs a user in and creates a claim for them. I am able to access the claim from a separate page in the application using the code below.

```
Dim claimsID As ClaimsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

What i can't figure out is how to also access the users token so that i can then use it for graph api calls.

This is the startup.vb

```
Imports Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
Imports Microsoft.Identity.Client
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(WEBCOMLogin.Startup))>
Namespace WEBCOMLogin
    Public Class Startup

        Private clientId As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ClientId")
        Private redirectUri As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RedirectUri")
        Shared tenant As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Tenant")
        Private authority As String = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Authority"), tenant)

        Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
                .clientId = clientId,
                .authority = authority,
                .redirectUri = redirectUri,
                .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                .Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                .ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                .ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost,
                .SaveTokens = True,
                .RedeemCode = True,
                .tokenvalidationparameters = New tokenvalidationparameters With {
                    .ValidateIssuer = False
                },
                .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications With {
                    .AuthenticationFailed = AddressOf OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                    .AuthorizationCodeReceived = AddressOf OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync
                }
            })
        End Sub

        Private Shared Function OnAuthenticationFailedAsync(ByVal notification As AuthenticationFailedNotification(Of OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
            notification.HandleResponse()
            Dim redirect As String = "owinerror.aspx?errormessage=" & notification.Exception.Message

            notification.Response.Redirect(redirect)
            Return Task.FromResult(0)
        End Function

        Private Async Function OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(ByVal notification As AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification) As Task

            Dim idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithTenantId(tenant).Build()

            Dim scopes As String = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile
            Dim result = Await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync()

            Dim userToken As String = result.AccessToken

        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you set SaveTokens = True, , the OpenIDConnect will pass the tokens (id/access/refresh) to the cookie handler and the cookie handler will by default store them inside the session cookie.

To later access the tokens you can in your controllers access them using:

```
string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

string idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");

string refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");

string tokenType = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("token_type");         

string accessTokenExpire = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");
```